# Python Matplotlib: How to remove error bar connecting lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='*')
plt.xscale('linear')
plt.yscale('linear')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=e, ecolour='k')
plt.show()
```

where x and y are numpy arrays of data points and e is also a numpy array of corresponding error intervals.

When I run this code it gives my a graph with the black (specified by ecolour='k') error lines and default blue connecting lines between the data points, how do I remove these blue connecting lines?

Or, alternatively, how do I specify the colour of the connecting lines separately? 'linespec' doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=e, ecolor='k', linestyle='')
```

UPDATE: just give a linestyle argument and set it to either None, '' or ' ' and it doesn't draw the connecting lines but keeps the error bars.

also correction to my post, it should be color not colour.

Comment: I have used this answer multiple times since I first searched for it, partly because matplotlib documentation is so spotty. Thanks!